# Pieces missing when printing more than first page is printed

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a program that allows the user to print out all of the pages of a report.  So far so good, except that when they are printing page 2 - the end, or even a page other than the first, there is a section that is missing.  When the pages show on the screen all the information is there, just not when it is finally printed.  The pages are generated through a while loop in php, here is a sample of the code that shows the html:

```
 <div id="page">
<div id="topper">
Book Condition:
    <?php echo $cond;?>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    Enter the PO that you would like to review: <?php echo $po;?><span id="record">Record <?php echo $x;?> of &nbsp;<?php echo $pages;?></span>
</div>
<div id="result">
<div class="width border cl">
    CL <?php echo $cl;?> 
</div>
<div id="recv" class="width border">
    REC: <?php echo $qty;?>
</div>
<div id="pricePd" class="width border">
    COST: <?php echo $paid;?>
</div>

<div id="words">    
    <div class="border old">Guide - Old</div>
    <div class="border mid">Qty Rem: <?php echo $qtyRem;?></div>
    <div class="border current">Guide - Current</div>   
</div><!--WORDS-->

<div id="box" class="border">
    <input value="<?php echo $title;?>" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="Title"/><br>
     <input value="<?php echo $isbn10;?>" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="ISBN10"/><br>
     <input id="isbn" value="<?php echo $isbn;?>" style="width: 200px;" placeholder="ISBN13" /><br>
</div><!--BOX-->

<div id="code" class="border">
    <div id="barcode" >
<?php  
echo '<img src="isbn/' .$isbn.'.jpg" width="200px;"height="100px;">';
?>
</div>
```

it is everything in the div with the id of "box" that does not print, except on the very first page.This only seems to happen in Firefox, when I print in chrome, all the info is there.
Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Why would you even print out inputs? Those are only useful when someone can actually type into them...so what purpose do they have on paper?

Comment: @slime  There is another part of this that is online and the inputs can be changed.  This is for attaching to items so we know where the decision to send them was and how many.

Comment: I was going to guess that the browsers don't like the inputs when trying to print, but you said it works on Chrome. Does that mean it only shows up on page 1 in Firefox, or doesn't show up at all in Firefox? And does that mean it shows up on all pages in Chrome?

Comment: shows on all pages in chrome, only on the first page in FF.  I installed the print edit add on for FF and that did not help.  Seems to work on some computers in my office, just not all of them....